Hyperledger Caliper - Can we build a work load module that can invoke and query from already deployed contract in the blockchain?
I am trying to benchmark a smart contract that interacts with an already deployed contract on the blockchain using Hyperledger Caliper. The overall framework is functioning correctly for other benchmarks, but it fails when the smart contract attempts to interact with the pre-deployed contract.
Here is a summary of the problem:
Framework: Hyperledger Caliper 
Blockchain: Ethereum 
Issue: Benchmarking fails at the point where the smart contract interacts with an already deployed contract.
